# OS X MDM Device Enrollment Fails with Nginx Proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, mdm, osx-server

I'm at my wits end trying to configure nginx as a transparent proxy to my OS X Server (in virtualbox) running our mdm service. Without nginx in the mix the mdm server works properly, and I can performce remote device enrollment and management, but I host multiple servers on the same network, and need to be able to proxy to multiple ips and ports using nginx.

The setup without nginx:
I'm using external DNS for my fqdn, mdm.servername.com, which is correctly resolving to my public ip address. I have my firewall successfully forwarding ports 443, and 1640 to my mdm server at private ip, 10.0.1.60. I have the OS X server DNS disabled, and *I'm also using mdm.servername.com as my OS Server's hostname*. I set mdm.servername.com to resolve to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts in order to build the open directory, and then I removed this entry from /etc/hosts. Don't know if this is one of the issues. I can access http://mdm.servername.com/mydevices from outside of the network, and enroll my ipad without problems. Everything is working properly until I introduce nginx.

The setup with nginx:
Again using external DNS for my fqdn, mdm.servername.com. I have nginx running on private ip 10.0.1.50, and I'm forwarding ports 443 and 1640 to 10.0.1.50. I have the OS X mdm server running on ip 10.0.1.50. The mdm server has DNS disabled, and the mdm server is also using mdm.servername.com as the OS hostname. I can still access the website portion of mdm (https://mdm.servername.com/mydevices), I can install the Trust Profile without any issues, but when I try to enroll my iPad from outside the network, it successfully "enrolls the certificate", but when it's "Installing Profile" it evenutally times out. I see the progression of api calls in the nginx access logs:

Nginx access.log

```
173.171.23.81 - - [16/Nov/2013:19:56:47 -0500] "GET /scep/?operation=GetCACert&message=Device%20Management%20Identity%20Certificate HTTP/1.1" 200 1126 "-" "profiled/1.0 CFNetwork/672.0.8 Darwin/14.0.0"
173.171.23.81 - - [16/Nov/2013:19:56:48 -0500] "GET /scep/?operation=GetCACaps&message=Device%20Management%20Identity%20Certificate HTTP/1.1" 200 52 "-" "profiled/1.0 CFNetwork/672.0.8 Darwin/14.0.0"
173.171.23.81 - - [16/Nov/2013:19:56:49 -0500] "POST /scep/?operation=PKIOperation HTTP/1.1" 200 3046 "-" "profiled/1.0 CFNetwork/672.0.8 Darwin/14.0.0"
173.171.23.81 - - [16/Nov/2013:19:58:20 -0500] "PUT /devicemanagement/api/device/mdm_checkin HTTP/1.1" 504 191 "-" "MDM/1.0"
```

The 504 error on the PUT happens about 30 seconds after the iPad already reports the profile installation failed.

Nginx error.log

```
2013/11/16 19:58:20 [error] 7983#0: *10 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xx.xx, server: mdm.servername.com, request: "PUT /devicemanagement/api/device/mdm_checkin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.0.1.60:443/devicemanagement/api/device/mdm_checkin", host: "mdm.servername.com"
```

So nginx is reporting a timeout talking to the mdm server for the PUT checkin action...

On the MDM Server the Apache Logs indicate connection errors also
Apache access_log

```
mdm.servername.com 10.0.1.50 - - [16/Nov/2013:19:56:47 -0500] "PUT /devicemanagement/api/device/mdm_checkin HTTP/1.0" 403 - "-" "MDM/1.0"
```

Apache error_log

```
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3328 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3329 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3327 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3325 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3326 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3324 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3322 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3323 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat Nov 16 19:56:22 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Sat Nov 16 19:58:17 2013] [error] [client 10.0.1.50] Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?
```

I'm assuming I have something misconfigured with nginx, but I'm not smart enough to put all these pieces together for a solution...Hopefully one you more capaple guys or gals can help me out...

Nginx Config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  types_hash_max_size 4096;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/servername.com/_.servername.com.combined.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/servername.com/_.servername.com.key;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 1640;

    server_name mdm.servername.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass $scheme://10.0.1.60:$server_port$request_uri;

      sendfile off;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

      #this is the maximum upload size
      client_max_body_size 10m;
      client_body_buffer_size 128k;

      proxy_connect_timeout 90;
      proxy_send_timeout 90;
      proxy_read_timeout 90;

      proxy_buffer_size 4k;
      proxy_buffers 4 32k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
      proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
  }
}
```

Additional info:
I have a wildcard ssl cert from go daddy that nginx is using for ssl, and I'm also using this for the websites server on OS X Server. I'm using the intermediate cert that Server generates for signing the configuration profile.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same errors as you about back end workers and still am.

Last night I spoke to an Apple Solutions Architect who felt that proxying Profile Manager was never going to work.

Apparently the reccomended solution is a CISCO security appliance that port forwards to ProfileManager in a DMZ. He suggested that SSL would think that Nginx was a man in the middle attack and that the PHP errors were a red herring. He also reccomended I check out http://twocanoes.com/push-diagnostics. Its £2.99 and I definitely reccomend it.

Today Enrollment was still failing - can't store Certification Authority Certificate, however there is hope.

Connect you iOS device to your Mac or PC with the iPhone Configuration Utility.

Take a look at the console, look for where it starts erroring, "Unable to insert in Sqlite, unable to duplicate". Checked the iPad has no profiles or certs installed - nothing installed.

Wiped the iPad and hit the enroll button and hey hey - it enrolled.

The iPad showed up correctly under Enrolment Profile Usage and in devices with all the correct info. When I left ProfileManger was pushing a profile. I seem to remember reading something about being able to delete the enrolment profile from the iPad but it never really deletes!

To make it work
Get the Push-diagnostic utility
I split the 1640 out of the server block into its own block in an attempt to make the Proxy as transparent as possible.
Wipe the iPad
Enroll

Happy days.

Regards

Stephen